# GWT Celltable-Sorting on Multiple Column

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

How to perform sorting on multiple column Using GWT Celltable. I didnt find any example code for this? See the below image

[image]

I need to Perform server side sorting on multiple column .How to Achieve this using GWT Celltable and how to add this arrow icon for more than one column.any clue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom header builder. You can use the one below (it supports the sorting sequence too, but you can remove it if you don't need it)

```
public class MultiSortHeaderOrFooterBuilder<T> extends AbstractHeaderOrFooterBuilder<T> {

    private static class ColumnSortInfoHolder {
        private ColumnSortInfo columnSortInfo;
        private int sortIndex;

        public ColumnSortInfoHolder(ColumnSortInfo columnSortInfo, int sortIndex) {
            this.columnSortInfo = columnSortInfo;
            this.sortIndex = sortIndex;
        }

        public int getSortIndex() {
            return sortIndex;
        }

        public ColumnSortInfo getColumnSortInfo() {
            return columnSortInfo;
        }
    }

    private final int sortAscIconWidth;
    private final int sortAscIconHalfHeight;

    private final int sortDescIconWidth;
    private final int sortDescIconHalfHeight;

    private SafeHtml sortAscIconHtml;
    private SafeHtml sortDescIconHtml;

    private static final int ICON_PADDING = 6;

    /**
     * Create a new DefaultHeaderBuilder for the header of footer section.
     * 
     * @param table
     *            the table being built
     * @param isFooter
     *            true if building the footer, false if the header
     */

    public MultiSortHeaderOrFooterBuilder(AbstractCellTable<T> table, boolean isFooter) {
        super(table, isFooter);

        ImageResource asc = table.getResources().sortAscending();
        ImageResource desc = table.getResources().sortDescending();
        if (asc != null) {
            sortAscIconWidth = asc.getWidth() + ICON_PADDING;
            sortAscIconHalfHeight = (int) Math.round(asc.getHeight() / 2.0);
        } else {
            sortAscIconWidth = 0;
            sortAscIconHalfHeight = 0;
        }
        if (desc != null) {
            sortDescIconWidth = desc.getWidth() + ICON_PADDING;
            sortDescIconHalfHeight = (int) Math
                    .round(desc.getHeight() / 2.0);
        } else {
            sortDescIconWidth = 0;
            sortDescIconHalfHeight = 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean buildHeaderOrFooterImpl() {

        AbstractCellTable<T> table = getTable();

        boolean isFooter = isBuildingFooter();
        if (isFooter)
            return false;

        // Early exit if there aren't any columns to render.
        int columnCount = table.getColumnCount();
        if (columnCount == 0) {
            // Nothing to render;
            return false;
        }

        // Early exit if there aren't any headers in the columns to render.
        boolean hasHeader = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
            if (table.getHeader(i) != null) {
                hasHeader = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (hasHeader == false) {
            return false;
        }
        HashMap<Column<?, ?>, ColumnSortInfoHolder> sortInfoByColumn = new HashMap<Column<?, ?>, ColumnSortInfoHolder>();
        // Set sorting information for multisort
        ColumnSortList sortList = table.getColumnSortList();
        if (table.getColumnSortList().size() > 0) {
            for (int colIdx = 0, sortPos = sortList.size(); colIdx < sortList.size(); colIdx++, sortPos--) {
                ColumnSortInfo columnSortInfo = sortList.get(colIdx);
                sortInfoByColumn.put(columnSortInfo.getColumn(), new ColumnSortInfoHolder(columnSortInfo, sortPos)); 
            }
        }

        // Get information about the sorted column.
        ColumnSortInfo sortedInfo = null;
        boolean isSortAscending = false;

        // Get the common style names.
        Style style = table.getResources().style();
        String className = isBuildingFooter() ? style.footer() : style.header();
        String sortableStyle = " " + style.sortableHeader();

        // Setup the first column.
        Header<?> prevHeader = getHeader(0);
        Column<T, ?> column = table.getColumn(0);
        int prevColspan = 1;
        boolean isSortable = false;
        boolean isSorted = false;
        StringBuilder classesBuilder = new StringBuilder(className);
        classesBuilder.append(" ").append(isFooter ? style.firstColumnFooter() : style.firstColumnHeader());
        if (!isFooter && column.isSortable()) {
            isSortable = true;
            sortedInfo = (sortInfoByColumn.get(column) != null) ? sortInfoByColumn.get(column).getColumnSortInfo() : null;
            isSortAscending = (sortedInfo != null) ? sortedInfo.isAscending() : false;
            isSorted = (sortedInfo != null);
        }

        // Loop through all column headers.
        TableRowBuilder tr = startRow();
        int curColumn;
        for (curColumn = 1; curColumn < columnCount; curColumn++) {

            Header<?> header = getHeader(curColumn);

            if (header != prevHeader) {
                // The header has changed, so append the previous one.
                if (isSortable) {
                    classesBuilder.append(sortableStyle);
                }
                if (isSorted) {
                    classesBuilder.append(getSortStyle(style, isSortAscending));
                }
                appendExtraStyles(prevHeader, classesBuilder);

                // Render the header.
                TableCellBuilder th = tr.startTH().colSpan(prevColspan)
                        .className(classesBuilder.toString());
                enableColumnHandlers(th, column);
                if (prevHeader != null) {
                    // Build the header.
                    Context context = new Context(0, curColumn - prevColspan, prevHeader.getKey());
                    // Add div element with aria button role
                    if (isSortable) {
                        th.attribute("role", "button");
                        th.tabIndex(-1);
                    }
                    renderRichSortableHeader(th, context, prevHeader, isSorted, isSortAscending, sortInfoByColumn);
                }
                th.endTH();

                // Reset the previous header.
                prevHeader = header;
                prevColspan = 1;
                classesBuilder = new StringBuilder(className);
                isSortable = false;
                isSorted = false;
            } else {
                // Increment the colspan if the headers == each other.
                prevColspan++;
            }

            column = table.getColumn(curColumn);
            if (!isFooter && column.isSortable()) {
                isSortable = true;
                sortedInfo = (sortInfoByColumn.get(column) != null) ? sortInfoByColumn.get(column).getColumnSortInfo() : null;
                isSortAscending = (sortedInfo != null) ? sortedInfo.isAscending() : false;
                isSorted = (sortedInfo != null);
            }
        }

        // Append the last header.
        if (isSortable) {
            classesBuilder.append(sortableStyle);
        }
        if (isSorted) {
            classesBuilder.append(getSortStyle(style, isSortAscending));
        }

        classesBuilder.append(" ").append(
                isFooter ? style.lastColumnFooter() : style.lastColumnHeader());

        appendExtraStyles(prevHeader, classesBuilder);

        // Render the last header.
        TableCellBuilder th = tr.startTH().colSpan(prevColspan).className(classesBuilder.toString());
        enableColumnHandlers(th, column);
        if (prevHeader != null) {
            Context context = new Context(0, curColumn - prevColspan, prevHeader.getKey());
            renderRichSortableHeader(th, context, prevHeader, isSorted, isSortAscending, sortInfoByColumn);
        }
        th.endTH();

        classesBuilder = new StringBuilder(style.header());
        classesBuilder.append(" ").append(style.lastColumnHeader());
        th = tr.startTH().className(classesBuilder.toString());
        th.endTH();

        // End the row.
        tr.endTR();

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Append the extra style names for the header.
     * 
     * @param header
     *            the header that may contain extra styles, it can be null
     * @param classesBuilder
     *            the string builder for the TD classes
     */
    private <H> void appendExtraStyles(Header<H> header, StringBuilder classesBuilder) {
        if (header == null) {
            return;
        }
        String headerStyleNames = header.getHeaderStyleNames();
        if (headerStyleNames != null) {
            classesBuilder.append(" ").append(headerStyleNames);
        }
    }

    private String getSortStyle(Style style, boolean isSortAscending) {
        return isSortAscending ? style.sortedHeaderAscending() : style.sortedHeaderDescending();
    }

    /**
     * Render a header, including a sort icon if the column is sortable and
     * sorted.
     * 
     * @param out
     *            the builder to render into
     * @param header
     *            the header to render
     * @param context
     *            the context of the header
     * @param isSorted
     *            true if the column is sorted
     * @param isSortAscending
     *            indicated the sort order, if sorted
     */
    protected void renderRichSortableHeader(ElementBuilderBase<?> out,
            Context context, Header<?> header, boolean isSorted,
            boolean isSortAscending,
            HashMap<Column<?, ?>, ColumnSortInfoHolder> sortIndexByColumn) {

        AbstractCellTable<T> table = getTable();

        ElementBuilderBase<?> headerContainer = out;
        boolean posRight = LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().isRTL();
        int iconWidth = 0;
        int sortIndexWidth = 0;

        if (isSorted) {
            // Create an outer container to hold the icon and the header.
            iconWidth = isSortAscending ? sortAscIconWidth : sortDescIconWidth;
            int halfHeight = isSortAscending ? sortAscIconHalfHeight : sortDescIconHalfHeight;
            DivBuilder outerDiv = out.startDiv();
            StylesBuilder style = outerDiv.style().position(Position.RELATIVE).trustedProperty("zoom", "1");

            style.endStyle();

            // Add the icon.
            DivBuilder imageHolder = outerDiv.startDiv();
            style = outerDiv.style().position(Position.ABSOLUTE).top(50.0, Unit.PCT).lineHeight(0.0, Unit.PX).marginTop(-halfHeight, Unit.PX);
            if (posRight) {
                style.right(0, Unit.PX);
            } else {
                style.left(0, Unit.PX);
            }
            style.overflow(Overflow.VISIBLE).endStyle();

            imageHolder.html(getSortIcon(isSortAscending));
            imageHolder.endDiv();

            if (table.getColumnSortList().size() > 0) {

                DivBuilder sortIndexHolder = outerDiv.startDiv();
                style = sortIndexHolder.style().position(Position.ABSOLUTE).top(0.0, Unit.PCT);
                sortIndexWidth = iconWidth - 2;
                if (posRight) {
                    style.right(sortIndexWidth, Unit.PX);
                } else {
                    style.left(sortIndexWidth, Unit.PX);
                }

                Column<T, ?> column = table.getColumn(context.getColumn());
                String sortIdx = String.valueOf(sortIndexByColumn.get(column).getSortIndex());
                sortIndexHolder.html(SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(sortIdx));
                sortIndexHolder.endDiv();
            }

            // Create the header wrapper.
            headerContainer = outerDiv.startDiv();
        }

        StylesBuilder style = headerContainer.style().position(Position.RELATIVE);
        if (posRight) {
            style.paddingRight(iconWidth + sortIndexWidth + 7, Unit.PX);
        } else {
            style.paddingLeft(iconWidth + sortIndexWidth + 7, Unit.PX);
        }
        style.endStyle();

        // Build the header.
        renderHeader(headerContainer, context, header);

        // Close the elements used for the sort icon.
        if (isSorted) {
            headerContainer.endDiv(); // headerContainer.
            headerContainer.endDiv(); // outerDiv
        }
    }

    private SafeHtml getSortIcon(boolean isAscending) {
        AbstractCellTable<T> table = getTable();
        if (isAscending) {
            if (sortAscIconHtml == null) {
                AbstractImagePrototype proto = AbstractImagePrototype.create(table.getResources().sortAscending());
                sortAscIconHtml = SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(proto.getHTML());
            }
            return sortAscIconHtml;
        } else {
            if (sortDescIconHtml == null) {
                AbstractImagePrototype proto = AbstractImagePrototype.create(table.getResources().sortDescending());
                sortDescIconHtml = SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(proto.getHTML());
            }
            return sortDescIconHtml;
        }
    }
}
```

You set it like this

```
CellTable<Contact> table = new CellTable<Contact>();
table.setHeaderBuilder(new MultiSortHeaderOrFooterBuilder<TableComponent.Contact>(table, false));
```

Comment: sorry Alkis,I didnt tried with this approach..but anyhow(+1)

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the upvote. If you find the time please post the approach you decided to follow, so others can benefit too. Doesn't have to be code. Have fun